# Read Jenkins environment variable from an application

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins job where I execute a groovy script. From within that groovy script I make a POST request to another application.
My Jenkins server and application are on different machines.
I need to get access to the Jenkins environment variable from within the application's code. Is this at all possible?

I have tried to retrieve the environment variable by using the **System.getenv("ENVIRONMENT-VARIABLE-NAME")** method, but the result returned is **null**.

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

I think, **It can't be**. If you are using `POST`, then you can send the variables as query/path params to your application.

You can get ur env variable in your **jenkins server** like this:

`${env.ENVIRONMENT_NAME}`

Comment: where should I use this piece of code. My application is groovy based. Will I be able to get the Jenkins environment variable, since my logic for fetching the environment variable resides in the application code and as I mentioned earlier, my application is running on a different server.

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick Now I understood. check my updated answer.